# RSA. Сравнение открытого и закрытого ключа

Tags: rsa

Доброго времени суток. 
Проблема такова. Нужно получить доступ к серверу через пару ключей. 
Создается 2 файла pubKey.xml и priKey.xml 
Как сравнить ключи в этих двух файлах?

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        //how to get the private key
        var privKey = csp.ExportParameters(true);
        //and the public key ...
        var pubKey = csp.ExportParameters(false);

        //Public key
        var sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        var xs = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(RSAParameters));
        xs.Serialize(sw, pubKey);
        string pubKeyString = sw.ToString();
        File.WriteAllText(path + "/pubKey.xml", pubKeyString);


        //PrivateKey
        var sw1 = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        var xs1 = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(RSAParameters));
        xs1.Serialize(sw1, privKey);
        string priKeyString = sw1.ToString();
        File.WriteAllText(path + "/priKey.xml", priKeyString);

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Публичный ключ содержит только 2 числа, которые так же есть в приватном ключе. Вам нужно их сравнить.

```
var sr = new System.IO.StringReader(File.ReadAllText("priKey.xml"));
var xs = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(RSAParameters));
var priv = (RSAParameters)xs.Deserialize(sr);

sr = new System.IO.StringReader(File.ReadAllText("pubKey.xml"));
var pub = (RSAParameters)xs.Deserialize(sr);

// дальше вы проверяете массивы байт, равна ли длина, совпадают ли данные в них
// priv.Exponent == pub.Exponent
// priv.Modulus == pub.Modulus
```